# When at / ( or "home") my menu doesn't get a current-menu-item class

Tags: menus, css, filters

I'm a wordpress noob tweaking a theme, so I'm trying to understand how it works.  I've read about 10 related posts in SE but don't get it yet.  My problem is as follows:

header.php seems to generate the menu with,

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'nav-menu','container'  => 'div', 'container_class' => 'menu' )); ?>
```

In the wp-admin, I've created a menu with

"Blog | About | Contact"

which point to the root and two pages: "/" | "about" | "contact"  (very standard).
Now, I'd like to style the menu depending on the "*active*" page.  For "*about*" and "*contact*" this seems very easy.  The classes generated for each menu item include **current-menu-item**.  However, when on the home page my "blog" menu "li" only gets the classes

```
menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47
```

and so cannot be styled accordingly.  I've read some stuff about filtering, using functions, etc ... but don't quite understand it.  If I define a function in functions.php, where would I use it afterwards.

Any insight and help is greatly appreciated,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get this to work you need to go to the menu admin and on the pages section click the tab that says *'view all'*. At the top of the list is a special option for your home page, whether it's the normal blog view or a specific page. Add that to the menu and you're good.

[image]

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

The menu can easily be generated using this code,

```
<ul>
                <li <?php if(is_home()) { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>><a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/">Home</a></li>
                <?php wp_list_pages('depth=1&sort_column=menu_order&title_li=' ); ?>
            </ul>
```

The function used to create a list of published pages, wp_list_pages(), automatically add a class current_page_item to the list item corresponding to the page you're viewing.

You just have to add the .current_page_item class to your style.css file:

```
/* Style the list element */
li.current_page_item{
background:#eee;
color:#777;
}

/* Style the link element */
li.current_page_item a{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: He's using wp_nav_menu, not wp_list_pages

Comment: I understand that code. thank you for the suggestion.  However I'll stick to wp_nav_menu as it's where I'm starting from.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty (and could be improved by dynamically picking up the menu item ID with php) but you can do this:

```
     <?php if (is_front_page()) echo
       '<style type="text/css" title="text/css">.menu-item-14 a
         {your current_page_item style here}</style>'
    ;?>
```

Change the .menu_item-14 to the class of the current home page and change the current_menu_item to your CSS, too.

Place that statement right after the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

in header.php so the CSS gets loaded after the main style sheet.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  it makes sense ... although it may be a complex thing to find if someone maintains the code later on.

Answer (score 0):

Strange that wordpress doesn't pick that page up as current page. But a easy solution is this (CSS only).

In your style.css

```
.home .menu-item-47 {
   /* current-menu-item styles */
}
```

Comment: Hi Rob. I can't see "home" and "menu-item-47" as  classes associated with "blog".  Rather I only see, "menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-47".  So, unless I'm missing something I don't think that CSS would target it.  Sanchothefat's solution solves it though.

Comment: The class home is a body class for the front-page (check the body element), so .home .menu-item-47 represents the menu-item-47 on the font-page. But anyway Sanchothefat's answer is indeed the right answer :-)